# Problem to use the commit:_config of napalm, not finding the config file

Tags: ios, python-3.x, cisco, cisco-ios, napalm

Hey guys I am  trying to test the commit of napalm, but it is not able to finding the cfg file, I also tried to change to "txt", but the same error.
Here my code:

```
import napalm
import json


driver = napalm.get_network_driver("ios")


device = driver(
    hostname="10.0.0.254",
    username="cisco",
    password="cisco",
    optional_args={"secret" : "cisco"}

)

device.open()

device.load_merge_candidate(filename="config.cfg")
device.commit_config()
device.close()
```

and this is the error,both files are in the same folder:

> user@user-pc:~/Documents/python_files$ /usr/bin/python3
>   /home/user/Documents/python_files/network/config_compare.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/Documents/python_files/network/config_compare.py", line
>   18, in 
>       device.load_merge_candidate(filename="config.cfg")   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/napalm/ios/ios.py",
>   line 315, in load_merge_candidate
>       return_status, msg = self._load_candidate_wrapper(   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/napalm/ios/ios.py",
>   line 282, in _load_candidate_wrapper
>       (return_status, msg) = self._scp_file(   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/napalm/ios/ios.py",
>   line 620, in _scp_file
>       return self._xfer_file(   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/napalm/ios/ios.py",
>   line 670, in _xfer_file
>       with TransferClass(**kwargs) as transfer:   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py",
>   line 278, in FileTransfer
>       return FileTransferClass(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/scp_handler.py",
>   line 80, in **init**
>       self.source_md5 = self.file_md5(source_file)   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/scp_handler.py",
>   line 257, in file_md5
>       with open(file_name, "rb") as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.c

tks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with a filepath, are you sure that 'config.cfg' is in the same dir as your code?

Try the below to see if you can access the file (if you can't you need to modify the filepath):

```
import napalm

driver = napalm.get_network_driver("ios")

device = driver(
    hostname="10.0.0.254",
    username="cisco",
    password="cisco",
    optional_args={"secret" : "cisco"}
)

device.open()

print('This is a config to be added:\n')

with open('config.cfg','r') as f:
    output = f.read()

device.load_merge_candidate(filename="config.cfg")
# I would add this to see what's you are merging:

print(device.compare_config())

confirm_config= input('Do you want to deploy the above config? Press Y to deploy \n')

if confirm_config == 'Y':
    device.commit_config()
    device.close() 
else:
    device.close()
```

Comment: Hey, tks again for your reply,
This are the path of my files,at least when I do a copy path in visual studio:
/home/users/Documents/python_files/network/config_compare.py
/home/users/Documents/python_files/network/config.cfg